# Compile pdo and pdo_mysql for PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to compile pdo.so and pdo_mysql.so to get pdo support on my PHP5 install.
I tried the following :

```
./configure --prefix=/thedirectory --with-mysql --with-pdo-mysql --enable-pdo
```

Compilation is successful but the .so aren't generated. 
I am supposed to have/specify a mysql installation?

Is the pdo support supposed to be compiled within php core ?
If I run a php -m I can see PDO and pdo_mysql registered, but a **phpinfo()** states no pdo_mysql support.
I guess the php -m just tells me php has pdo support but still need the .so?

Could anyone advise?

Thanks

Comment: Which system do you use? PDO is included in the newest versions. Why do you compile it?

Comment: Your PHP CLI binary has PDO support compiled in. The PHP binary used by your web server does not. I think in order to generate the so files you will need to `configure` / `make` / `make install` - `configure` normally just generates a makefile, it doesn't actually compile it... How are you running PHP, against which web server? Apache/mod_php or CGI/FCGI?

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
I'm using a redhat 4 linux, I have been provided a compiled package of 5.2.17, but on which pdo_mysql doens't work as I get "Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' "
So i'm trying to add the support by putting the pdo.so and pdo_mysql.so in extensions folder and modify php.ini to use these extensions.

I'm trying to compile from php-5.4.3 sources.
Of course I ran make & make install and it was successful but as said, it doesn't generate the .so

I am using PHP2.2 with mod_php5.so

Comment: @lepolac If you get as far as a `PDOException`, you don't need to worry about `pdo.so`. If you're using redhat, can't you just get it with rpm?

Comment: @DaveRandom oh yeah you are right, pdo is probably enabled then. In fact the phpinfo tells me pdo_sqlite is enabled, but not mysql.
The easy rpm solution only exists in an ideal world which is not mine unfortunately :'(. Don't have access to it, and I'm building all this in custom locations anyway.

Comment: I'll hold my hands up and say I've never actually built PHP extension into an so on Linux before, only ever built DLLs on Windows and I just recompile the PHP binary with static support for the given module on *nix. However, I'm wondering if you might need to `phpize` like [this](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php)

Comment: Ow, nice guess, thanks !
I have been able to compile the .so from sources.
But now, being referenced in my php.ini, apache throws me :


PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'pdo.so'  in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'pdo_mysql.so'  in Unknown on line 0

So I wonder if the PHP version I am trying to insert the .so is too old or something.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following configure options:

```
./configure \
--with-mysqli=/home/user/programs/mysql/install/bin/mysql_config \
--with-pdo-mysql=/home/user/programs/mysql/install
```

The `/home/user/programs/mysql/install` directory is where MySQL has been installed.

You should see a `pdo_mysql` section in the phpinfo() output showing the following:

```
PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  5.7.16
```

Answer (score -3):

The latest versions of PHP come with PDO drivers for MySQL, Oracle, PgSQL, ODBC, SQLite and Firebird/Interbase. All you have to do is enable them in your `php.ini`:

```
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

Here I have MySQL, and PgSQL enabled while all others are disabled.

(This is from a php.ini file from Windows, but on linux it looks pretty much the same, just the extensions are in the form of `pdo_mysql.so`, `pdo_pgsql.so`, etc.)